# I cannot access website on VM in Hyper -V within LAN

Tags: routing, virtualization, reverse-proxy, hyper-v, nat

Good day great minds,

i cannot access my webserver behind an nginx reverse proxy within my LAN network.

i have a mikrotic router with a LAN network 192.168.143.0/24, i deployed an hyper V server that has a NICTeam with a static IP 192.168.143.165 and a gateway 192.168.143.1

i created an external Vswitch with the multiplexor from the NIC and shared it with and internal Vswitch through the properties window of the external vswitch. i configured   the NAT for the internal vswitch so that my webservers can have access to internet. After this, i deployed 4 webserver with the internal vswitch on network 192.168.138.0/24 (DHCP not enabled and no gateway), 1 nginx reverse proxy to direct traffic to the other 3 VMs. All VMs can see the internet and working perfectly. However, for some reasons that i cannot figure out, i can access the webserver from within the Hyper V host and outside the whole network but i cannot access the webserver from any ip address within 192.168.143.0/24 network which happens to be our major network and where majority of the users are. these are the steps i have taken but with no success.

1. add IP route 192.168.143.0, the mask and its gateway
2. add ip route 192.168.138.0/24 the mask and its gateway
3. deployed RRAS and NAT in windows server 2019 with 2 NIC with 192.168.143.0/24 as internet and 192.168.138.0/24 as LAN
4. added the ip addresses and FQDN in the host config within the Hyper V host
5. did an nslookup for all the domains from a client machine within the 192.168.143.0/24 network and the path seems to go through the public ip rather than reference the local ip address.

i have open all necessary port on the reverse proxy, webservers and also Hyper V host.

also i tried to ping the VM from any client within 192.168.143.0/24 network, i had no response. meanwhile i could ping the client from the VM in the internal switch.

i had read through many routing articles but cannot seem to find a solution to the problem. i am not certain if the problem is caused by reverse proxy i deployed which i really need because of shortage of public address available. please any idea as to what i could have done wrong or not done at all.

Comment: `the path seems to go through the public ip rather than reference the local ip address.` All of that and there is no information on the internal DNS record?